# php check if at least two checkbox is checked and display a message to user

Tags: php

```
<div class='container'><label for='vehicle'>Vehicle:</label><br/>
 <span id='contactus_vehicle_errorloc' class='error'></span>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="bike" value=<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('bike') ?> /> I have a bike<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="car" value=<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('car') ?> /> I have a car <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="motorbike" value=<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('motorbike') ?> /> I have a motorbike <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="plane" value=<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('plane') ?> /> I have a plane <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="papaki" value=<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('papaki') ?> /> I have a papaki <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible that parts of the code is missing?

Comment: Will you inform user after page rendered or when user click or something?

Answer (score 1):

it's simple - sum all the values, and if it's at least two, then you're ok.

Answer (score 1):

Hi To count number of checked checkbox.

1. replace `name="vehicle"` with `name="vehicle[]"`. by this change in post value of vehicle an array of checked values will be come.

and then in php file

```
if(isset($_POST['vehicle'])){
     /*check atleast 2 checked*/  
     if(sizeof($_POST['vehicle']) > 1){
       //code comes here
    }
  }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't know abotu the IDs, it only knows about the names. Change the name to:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" ///>
```

Then you can check in PHP like this:

```
<?php
if (count($_POST['vehicle]') >= 2) {
  //do something
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

change name like this name="vehicle[]" then in your page

```
if (count($vehicle) < 2){
 echo "please select at least two fields";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**your code will be like:**

Vehicle:
 
SafeDisplay('bike') ?> /> I have a bike
SafeDisplay('car') ?> /> I have a car 
SafeDisplay('motorbike') ?> /> I have a motorbike 
SafeDisplay('plane') ?> /> I have a plane 
SafeDisplay('papaki') ?> /> I have a papaki